# Why contentView has a y-offset inside a scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I try to add a subview(UIView) to scrollView to position the content in scrollView, but I was confused about why the scrollable content starts with a certain offset.

**My view hierarchy and constrains look like this**

[image]

**When I run the application(the scroll view has a pink background, and the content view has a black background color)**

[image]

**In my story board, it looks like this**

[image]

In case this might help, in my viewDidAppear method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print(view.frame)
        print(baseView.frame) 
        print(scrollView.frame)
        print(scrollView.bounds)
        print(scrollView.contentSize)
        print(contentView.frame)
    }
```

I got

```
  (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 618.0)
    (0.0, 64.0, 375.0, 554.0)
    (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 554.0)
    (0.0, -64.0, 375.0, 554.0) //Why there is a negative y-offset here?
    (375.0, 1200.0)        
    (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 1200.0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that the scroll view is under the status bar and navigation bar (starts at `y = 0`).

The height of the navigation bar = `44 points`
The height of the status bar = `20 points`

In total `64 points`.

Usually the scroll view starts at `y = 0` so the `UIViewController` automatically changes its content insets so that the content is not hidden under the top bars.

See [UIViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)

You should set it to `false` on your controller.

Comment: As for Swift 4, it is now `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` property on `UIScrollView`

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan Not related to Swift. I think it's from iOS 9 or iOS 10.

Comment: @Sulthan iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad :

```
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
```